# Failed to review a answer

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, new-users

You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11044857.

Ok... so I reviewed an answer and putted up No Action Needed. Then system told me that I should stop and carefully read everything. I've read it in the first place, and it's a simple querry that I understood it's ok.

Why is this answer so so bad that I made an incorrect review?

Comment: The answer could use a comment or a downvote. The two question marks deserve noting at the very least.

Comment: I thought that it was an obvious solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this answer was bad enough that choosing "No Action Needed" was not the correct course of action.

I cannot give more guidance than the help on that review queue

> No Action Needed when this post needs no action from you.
>
> I'm Done is only available if you've done one of the following:
>       - Vote up or down to rate the answer's helpfulness
>       - Edit to improve the answer's appearance, clarity, or accuracy
>       - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments
>       - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems
>       - Delete answers that do not attempt to answer the question
>
> Be sure to leave a comment if you can help the user out, or click Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next item.

In this case, it would have been appropriate to probably comment that code-only answers are of limited usefulness, or that some description of the proposed fix would be beneficial. You could have also simply voted it down (if it did not answer the question appropriately)

Comment: Ok. I'll review more carefully in future.